# How to prove the Grassmann identity in vector form?

Tags: products

I am given the following question: Show that for all vectors a,b,c the Grass-mann identity holds:
$$ a\times (b\times c)\text {=} (a\cdot c)b - (a\cdot b)c $$
I have tried entering the above identity in to Mathematica as:
`Cross[a, Cross[b, c]] === (a.c) b - (a.b) c`
However, when I try and execute it I get a `False`. I also tried entering it exactly the same way as in the above equation from the question using the Basic math assistant just with a `===` instead of a single `=` but it also returns a `False`. Can someone explain what am I doing wrong and what would be the correct way of checking the identity and why.

Comment: `a\[Cross](b\[Cross]c) // TensorExpand`

Comment: TensorExpand[a\[Cross](b\[Cross]c), 
 Assumptions -> {{a | b | c} \[Element] Vectors[d]}]. This works, as I learnd from Carl Woll, but TensorExpand can be quite tricky at times.

Comment: `n = 3; a = Array[av, n]; b = Array[bv, n]; c = Array[cv, n]; Cross[a, Cross[b, c]] == (a.c) b - (a.b) c // Simplify`

Comment: @xzczd even if I use this notation instead of ```Cross[a, Cross[b, c]]``` I still get a False. Could you please elaborate how I am supposed to use this command?

Comment: @BobHanlon why does the array deceleration help? Is it because a,b,c all become 3 dimensional and thus the equation can be solved in vector form?

Comment: `===` is not for this purpose, it only checks if two expressions are literally the same. Try `a===1`. You need to use `==` instead. For more info please check the document of them carefully by pressing F1.